# Como arreglar el error system.argumentexception:option not supported

Tags: c#, mysql, base-de-datos, visual-studio, mysql-workbench

Al intentar establecer la conexión para guardar datos entre C# y MySql me arroja el siguiente error

[image: Error generado]

y este es el codigo que tengo escrito
[image: Codigo escrito]

Comment: Hola Juan Felipe, aunque esta pregunta parece interesante, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, edítala para corregir algunas cosas (p.e. pon el código y los errores como texto en lugar de como imágenes). Completa el [tour] y lee sobre cómo crear un [mve] donde encontrarás recomendaciones para mejorar tus preguntas y que sean mejor recibidas. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que el parametro `Data Bases` esta mal.

Te dejo un ejemplo.

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```